# QQuickPaintedItem update function does not redraw when using it for loading a new QImage

Tags: c++, image, qt, qml

I am displaying an image in QT C++ with QQuickPaintedItem, the first draw works fine however when I want to load a new image the paint function is not called. I narrowed it down to a simple example where a button is clicked and the new image should be loaded. I am using a stackview, so I have a .ui.qml file and a qml file.

The Header File:

```
#ifndef IMAGEITEM_H
#define IMAGEITEM_H


#include <QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>

class ImageItem : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QImage image READ image WRITE setImage NOTIFY imageChanged)
public:
    ImageItem(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void setImage(const QImage &image);
    void paint(QPainter *painter);
    QImage image() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void toggleImage();
signals:
    void imageChanged();
private:
    QImage current_image;
};

#endif // IMAGEITEM_H
```

The Cpp file. Here the function "toggleImage" is the one being called when pressing the button. It gets called, but the paint function won't get called.

```
#include "imageitem.h"

ImageItem::ImageItem(QQuickItem *parent) : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{
    //adapt this accordint to your location of the image!
    this->current_image = QImage("file:/../../SimpleImageSwitcher/1.png");
}

void ImageItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QRectF bounding_rect = boundingRect();
    QImage scaled = this->current_image.scaledToHeight(bounding_rect.height());
    QPointF center = bounding_rect.center() - scaled.rect().center();

    if(center.x() < 0)
        center.setX(0);
    if(center.y() < 0)
        center.setY(0);
   painter->drawImage(center, scaled);
}

QImage ImageItem::image() const
{    return this->current_image;
}

void ImageItem::toggleImage()
{
    qDebug() << "image changer called!";
    QImage img = QImage("file:/../../SimpleImageSwitcher/2.png");
    this->setImage(img);
    emit imageChanged();
}

void ImageItem::setImage(const QImage &image)
{
    this->current_image = image;
    update();
}
```

The main cpp where I register the Image view and set the context property:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "imageitem.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));

    ImageItem imageengine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("imageEngine",&imageengine);
    qmlRegisterType<ImageItem>("imageView", 1, 0, "ImageItem");


    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

The ui.qml called HomeForm.ui.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import imageView 1.0

Page {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    property alias button: button
    property alias test: button

    title: qsTr("Home")

    ImageItem {
      id: liveImageItem
      height: parent.height
      width: parent.width
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        text: "change"
        anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -180
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: -250
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

...and the main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import imageView 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Stack")

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: "HomeForm.ui.qml"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    HomeForm {
        button.onClicked: imageEngine.toggleImage()
    }

}
```

When I tried to debug the functions and stepped in to the `update()` function it went out of the functions right after this line: `Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR QRect() noexcept : x1(0), y1(0), x2(-1), y2(-1) {}`. What does that mean? I read that a lot of times the width and the height of the Rectangle where the image is displayed must be set but I did so.  Thank you for your help

Comment: You have two object inctances of your ImageItem class. The 'liveImageItem' is the one that is displayed, but you call 'toggleImage()' on the c-side-created one ('imageEngine').

Usually you do not create QQuickItems in main(), only in QML files. So just get rid of 'imageEngine' and call 'liveImageItem.toggleImage()'

Comment: Thanks, additionaly the liveImageItem needs to exposed via an alias